# How can I resolve "The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)"?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to access the values of questionText from questions.
When I am trying to extract String values from a map, the following error is displayed on Flutter. (The code is written in Dart):

> The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type
> 'String'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)

**Error**:

[image]

This is my **main.dart** file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './question.dart';

import './answer.dart';

// void main() {
//   runApp(MyApp());
// }

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _questionIndex = 0;

  void _answerQuestion() {
    setState(() {
      _questionIndex += 1;
    });
    print(_questionIndex);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var questions = [
      {
        'questionText': 'What\'s your favorite color?',
        'answers': ['Black', 'Red', 'Green', 'White'],
      },
      {
        'questionText': 'What\'s your favorite animal?',
        'answers': ['Rabbit', 'Snake', 'Elephant', 'Lion'],
      },
      {
        'questionText': 'Who\'s your favorite instructor?',
        'answers': ['Max', 'Max', 'Max', 'Max'],
      },
    ];
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My First App'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
```

**Error on this line:**

```
    Question(
                  questions[_questionIndex]['questionText'],
                ),
                Answer(_answerQuestion),
                Answer(_answerQuestion),
                Answer(_answerQuestion),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

This is my **question.dart** file:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class Question extends StatelessWidget {
      final String questionText;
    
      Question(this.questionText);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Text(
            questionText,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to let dart know the type of `questions[_questionIndex]['questionText']`

Try this:

Change `questions[_questionIndex]['questionText']`

to `questions[_questionIndex]['questionText'] as String`

In the error line

Or You can rewrite as:
`questions[_questionIndex]['questionText'] ?? ''`

Answer (score 3):

Replace `question[_questionIndex]['questionText']` By `question[_questionIndex]['questionText']` as `String`

Comment: Azer Laribi, while this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.